# spider stuck when use scrapy and tor

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler, tor

http://pkmishra.github.io/blog/2013/03/18/how-to-run-scrapy-with-TOR-and-multiple-browser-agents-part-1-mac/

I install tor and scrapy for crawl some webpages and the first days it run very well. and somedays It stuck there. 'scrapy shell 'url' ' and it print out those below in the terminal.

I thougt the tor was down , but 'torsocks curl 'https://api.ipify.org' ' returns a real ip ,and change regularly.

```
2016-11-20 19:04:41 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled downloader middlewares:
['scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpauth.HttpAuthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.downloadtimeout.DownloadTimeoutMiddleware',
 'scrapy_spider.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware',
 'scrapy_spider.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.defaultheaders.DefaultHeadersMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.MetaRefreshMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.redirect.RedirectMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.chunked.ChunkedTransferMiddleware',
 'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.stats.DownloaderStats']
2016-11-20 19:04:41 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled spider middlewares:
['scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror.HttpErrorMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.referer.RefererMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.urllength.UrlLengthMiddleware',
 'scrapy.spidermiddlewares.depth.DepthMiddleware']
2016-11-20 19:04:41 [scrapy] INFO: Enabled item pipelines:
[]
2016-11-20 19:04:41 [scrapy] DEBUG: Telnet console listening on 127.0.0.1:6024
2016-11-20 19:04:41 [scrapy] INFO: Spider opened
```

When I comment the code below in 'settings.py', 'scrapy shell 'url'' turns well.So what's the problem, and how to locate the bugs if happens next time ?

```
USER_AGENT_LIST = [
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/535.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/16.0.912.36 Safari/535.7',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64; rv:16.0) Gecko/16.0 Firefox/16.0',
    'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_7_3) AppleWebKit/534.55.3 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/5.1.3 Safari/534.53.10'
]
HTTP_PROXY = 'http://127.0.0.1:8123'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_spider.middlewares.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'scrapy_spider.middlewares.ProxyMiddleware': 410,
    'scrapy.contrib.downloadermiddleware.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    # Disable compression middleware, so the actual HTML pages are cached
}
```

Comment: What's your DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT settings? I remember the default timeout being 60 seconds, maybe try set it to 5 and see if it's just slow internet?